# Extend a Scheme list using the same list values

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I need to create a Scheme function that receives a list and a desired new size, the function then extends the list size by using the same list values. For example:

```
'(1 2 3) to size 6 will turn to '(1 2 3 1 2 3)
'(1 2) to size 5 will turn to '(1 2 1 2 1)
'(4 5 6 1) to size 7 will turn to '(4 5 6 1 4 5 6)
```

The new length function parameter can be equal or bigger than the current list size.

Comment: Sort of, it's a project that I take at school and it's just a small part of something bigger.

Comment: In that case, you probably want to use the standard Racket language, rather than Pretty Big. The latter is pretty outdated (or so Eli Barzilay tells me).

Comment: Yes I know but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use something other than Pretty Big. My other colleagues are using it so I have to use it as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html) function `circular-list` (alongside Racket's built-in `take`) to do this:

```
(require srfi/1)
(define (take-circular lst n)
  (take (apply circular-list lst) n))
```

If you want to avoid using SRFI 1, another method works like this:

```
(define (take-circular lst n)
  (let ((size (length lst)))
    (if (> n size)
        (append lst (take-circular lst (- n size)))
        (take lst n))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually can't use SRFI 1, so I tried the second codde but it didn't work. First it said that the word `take` is undefined so I've changed that to `circular-list` and now the program get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Which language are you using in Racket? `take` is defined if you're using the standard Racket language (`#lang racket`).

Comment: Oh I really forgot to mention that, sorry. The language I use is Pretty Big.

Comment: In that case, just define `take` yourself. `(take lst n)` simply returns a new list with the first `n` elements of `lst`.